# actions on google - alpha and beta test opt-in link does not work on iOS and Android

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have successfully deployed my google assistant action to Alpha and Beta, however, the testing opt-in link does not provide access to my app. It simply does not work.

Quick recap:
- I have deployed action to Beta
- I have whitelisted some users
- I have sent them an opt-in link

- Testers copied link to the notepad
- They've opened a link in Google Assistant app
- They've seen a blank page
  ![blank page screenshot] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hfL0Ix0dGkhz4R9Qwc_Y1T058YZDUXDa/view

![screen recording] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhIQHk2KtH4jQVXr5EL4FJGGSrIbDSGe/view

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for posting! This seems more likely to be a one-off issue than a platform issue, so I recommend you seek advice from Google's support team instead of Stack Overflow. You can reach them at https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: @MaxWiederholt I doubt that this is a one-off issue, I always have problems with these links as well. Sometimes they work after a day or two, but at that point my testers enthusiasm has usually faded.